# Nested click event on list is making multiple calls

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items

If I click on list 1,-> 2,-> 3 and then I click on `Btn` it is running as many times I clicked before clicking on `Btn`

Here is sample Demo

```js
$('li.list-group-item').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.circle-btn').on('click', function(p) {
    alert('check');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info buy-now-btn circle-btn">
    Btn<br>
    <span class="askingAmt"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item row">
    1
  </li>
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item row">
    2
  </li>
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item row">
    3
  </li>
</div>
```

How do I make sure only last clicked item should perform the `.circle-btn` click?

even I tried using `e.stopPropogation()` after the first click but did not help

Comment: Use `e.stopPropogation()` inside `$('.circle-btn').on('click', function(p) {` function to bottom of `alert()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this code:

```
$('li.list-group-item').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.circle-btn').on('click', function(p) {
    alert('check');
  });
})
```

Basically, what you're doing is whenever there is a click event on `.list-group-item`, you subscribe to one ***new*** click event handler, which means there will be identical event handlers defined 15 times, if you clicked `.list-group-item` 15 times.

Just move the inside click listener out of the outer click listener.

Comment: no, I can't I have made it simple here to find a solution but on the first click, it fetches all the blockchain status, address, and balance which is related to that list item and then I need to perform the second click with that data. Is there any work around using this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.list-group-item').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.circle-btn').on('click', function(p) {
    alert('check');
  });
})
```

This code add for each elements in list event on btn. If u need only one event, on button click you need this code:

```
  $('.circle-btn').on('click', function(p) {
    alert('check');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `e.stopPropogation()` or `p.stopPropogation()` method inside `$('.circle-btn').on('click', function(p)` this to bottom of **`alert()`** method.

```js
$('.list-group-item').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.circle-btn').on('click', function(p) {
    alert('check');
    e.stopPropogation();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container my-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info circle-btn">Button <span class="askingAmt"></span></button>
      <div class="list my-3">
        <div class="list-group-item">1</div>
        <div class="list-group-item">2</div>
        <div class="list-group-item">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```